# Dataweave 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: dataweave

Trying to convert the below dataweave from 1.0 to 2.0, but everything I've tried gives one of the following errors. Any ideas please on how to write the same in dataweave 2.0?

Invalid input "map {Entity: $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..2", expected PropertyName or ?
Invalid input "filter (($.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..3", expected PropertyName or ?

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
%function checkNull(value) '' when value == null otherwise value
---
payload.MMAP_SUPPLIER_DETAILS_OBJ_TYPE.SITES.*MMAP_SUPPLIER_SITE_OBJ_TYPE 
    filter (($.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..3] == 'CHN '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..3] == 'FDL '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..3] == 'HPP '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..3] == 'MEX '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..3] == 'P&A '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..3] == 'STC ')
             and ($.ORG_ID == '116' or $.ORG_ID == '5195')
            and checkNull($.INACTIVE_DATE) == '')
    map {
        Entity: $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..2]
    }


%dw 2.0
output application/java
fun checkNull(value) = if (value == null) '' else value
---
payload.MMAP_SUPPLIER_DETAILS_OBJ_TYPE.SITES.*MMAP_SUPPLIER_SITE_OBJ_TYPE
    filter (($.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..3] == 'CHN '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..3] == 'FDL '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..3] == 'HPP '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..3] == 'MEX '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..3] == 'P&A '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..3] == 'STC ')
            and ($.ORG_ID == '116' or $.ORG_ID == '5195')
            and checkNull($.INACTIVE_DATE) == '')
    map {
        Entity: $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0..2]
    }
```

Comment: What is the input and what is the script for DataWeave 2 that caused that error?

Comment: Moreover, you should also provide the DW 2.0 expression you have tried.

Comment: If you happen to have a local version of DW. 2.0 playground running on your machine, you can simply copy and paste the DW 1.0 script and it will generate the equivalent DW 2.0 script for you. The same works with the IntelliJ plugin for DW as well. However that feature is not yet present in dwlang.fun.

Comment: dwlang.fun 2.0 playground has moved:

https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave/playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things have changed. First, the output isn't prefaced with a `%`, and if statements are now in the format of `if (condition) result else otherResult`. Ranges are also now specified using `START to FINISH`, eg: `0 to -1` selects the entire range.

Try this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
fun checkNull(value) = if (value == null) '' else value
---
payload.MMAP_SUPPLIER_DETAILS_OBJ_TYPE.SITES.*MMAP_SUPPLIER_SITE_OBJ_TYPE 
    filter (($.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0 to 3] == 'CHN '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0 to 3] == 'FDL '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0 to 3] == 'HPP '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0 to 3] == 'MEX '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0 to 3] == 'P&A '
             or $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0 to 3] == 'STC ')
             and ($.ORG_ID == '116' or $.ORG_ID == '5195')
            and checkNull($.INACTIVE_DATE) == '')
    map {
        Entity: $.VENDOR_SITE_CODE[0 to 2]
    }
```

Like @aled mentioned though it would be helpful to see the input and expected output.

Comment: Thanks Michael.
I copied/pasted what you sent into my Mulesoft app's transform message, no error, deployed successfully, ran a couple tests, and it worked as I expected it to.
What I did was copy/paste the dataweave 1.0 code from my Mule 3 app into notepad, edited it, then copy/paste it into my Mule 4 transform (what I was using shown below), which resulted in the 'filter' error in my original post above, but looks similar to yours. Maybe a line break or something from copy/paste into and out of Notepad that I couldn't see. Won't be using Notepad for this anymore.

Comment: Correction, I added what I was using to my original post above. Must have been some line break, tab, or etc. ... something I couldn't see, that was causing the error.
Thanks again Michael!

Comment: note, you can replace `if (value==null) ...` by using `value default ''`' and remove the customer function altogether. See https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-cookbook-defaults#example-of-using-the-keyword-default-to-set-a-default-value more information

Comment: Realistically, you'd probably be better off just using `isEmpty` for that anway, instead of doing a filter where `(value default '') == ''`